# Multiline output to single line concatenation with delimiter string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, paste

I use this command to get a list of all the files that has changed in a pull-request.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD master
```

Sample output:

```
my/repo/file1.java
my/repo/file3.java
my/repo/file5.java
```

I would like to convert this output to the following:

```
file:my/repo/file1.java||file:my/repo/file3.java||file:my/repo/file5.java
```

so that I can run code analysis only on these files from IntelliJ IDEA.

**What have I tried so far?**

```
git diff --name-only HEAD master |  sed -e 's/^/file:/'  | paste -s -d "||" -
```

This gives me the following output:

```
file:my/repo/file1.java|file:my/repo/file3.java|file:my/repo/file5.java
```

Notice the single `|`.

Also, please simplify the command if possible.

Edit: None of the files will have a whitespace or a newline in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it with `awk`

```bash
git diff --name-only HEAD master |
awk 'NR > 1 {printf("||")} {printf("file:%s",$0)} END{print ""}'
```

What this awk does is:

- for all input lines **but the first**, output: `||`
- for all input lines, output: `file:` + `<input line content>`
- when there's no more input lines to read, output a **newline** character

**remark:** the `END{print ""}` is unrequited when you do `out=$(git .. | awk ...)`

Comment: This doesn't add the delimiter `||` and `file:` between the last and the second last line.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add `""` as argument to the last `print`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `git... | awk` solution:

```bash
git diff --name-only HEAD master |
awk '{printf "%sfile:%s", (NR>1?"||":""), $0} END{print ""}'
```

Or a more nifty `awk` solution (works with BSD/Mac awk also):

```bash
git diff --name-only HEAD master |
awk -v RS= -v OFS='||' '{$1=$1} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD master| sed s'/^/file:/;:a;N;s/\n/||file:/;ba'
file:my/repo/file1.java||file:my/repo/file3.java||file:my/repo/file5.java
```

Comment: I'm on MacOS and this produces multiline output with `sed: 1: "s/^/file:/;:a;N;s/\n/|| ...": unused label 'a;N;s/\n/||file:/;ba'`

Comment: @Saif Does `sed -e 's/^/file:/;:a;N;s/\n/||file:/' -e 'ba'` work?

Comment: Naah, no output ```sed: 2: "ba
": undefined label 'a'
```

Comment: @Saif I do not have a Mac to test on at this time. You can see it work here https://ideone.com/QJVApr

Comment: Got you. Thanks a lot! I would have given you access to my terminal, then I saw what you have put on your profile.

Comment: @Saif Lol. Try this `sed -e 's/^/file:/' -e ':a' -e 'N' -e 's/\n/||file:/' -e 'ba'` It seperates all the commands

Comment: No output at all.

Comment: @Saif It may be an idea to install GNU sed if you do not have it. `brew install gnu-sed`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a Mac, might as well use `zsh` instead of its ancient outdated version of `bash` (Plus no using extra processes or programs, just `zsh` substitutions):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

#data=$(git diff --name-only HEAD master)

data="my/repo/file1.java                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
my/repo/file3.java                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
my/repo/file5.java"

typeset -a files=( "${(@f)data}" ) # Split on newlines
combined=${(j:||:)files[@]/#/file:} # Add file: to every element and join with ||

# file:my/repo/file1.java||file:my/repo/file3.java||file:my/repo/file5.java
print "$combined"
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of delimiters to `paste` is a list of consecutive single-character delimiters to be used for columns.

```
$ paste -d 'abc' <(seq 0 3) <(seq 3 6) <(seq 6 9) <(seq 9 12)
0a3b6c9
1a4b7c10
2a5b8c11
3a6b9c12
```

There is a simple trick - you can make `paste` join lines with a single-char delimiter, and then replace the single char by multi-char that you want to have.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD master | paste -sd '|' | sed 's/|/||/g'
```

You can also use bash to replace newlines with `||`. Fun fact: command substitution `$(..)` removes trailing newlines.

```
a=$(git diff --name-only HEAD master); echo "${a//$'\n'/||}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD master |
    awk '{printf "%sfile:%s", sep, $0; sep="||"} END{if (sep) print ""}'
file:my/repo/file1.java||file:my/repo/file3.java||file:my/repo/file5.java
```

The above:

1. Will not print a blank line given no input, it'll produce no output, and
2. Does not read the whole input into memory, it just reads 1 line at a time, and
3. Uses a mandatory POSIX tool, awk, with no non-portable extensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
"${input….}" |
{m,g}awk 'sub("^", "file:", $!(NF = NF))^+!+--NF' \
          FS='\n|[|]+[^:/]+:$' RS='^$' OFS='||file:' 

 
my/repo/file1.java
my/repo/file3.java
my/repo/file5.java
 
 
file:my/repo/file1.java||file:my/repo/file3.java||file:my/repo/file5.java
```